# Рандомайзер папки с картинками

Tags: c++

Мне нужно брать рандомную картинку из папки. Картинка может быть названа как угодно и картинок может быть сколько угодно, известно только расширение - jpg и саму папку.
Вот код:

```
auto foo(void) {
    std::vector < std::string > vecImg;
    std::string path = "./testimg/day";
    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path)) {
        vecImg.push_back(entry.path());
    }
    return rand() % vecImg.size();
}
```

Но в push_back положить нельзя, какой тип можно указать и вообще правильно ли я делаю?
Нужно возвращать путь к картинке, например, **./testimg/day/jdsai.jpg**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пишите: "Нужно возвращать путь к картинке".

А возвращаете `rand() % vecImg.size()`, то есть `int`.

Я думаю стоит написать так:

```
return vecImg[rand() % vecImg.size()];
```

Так же, вам нужно из `path` получить `string`, чтобы запихнуть путь в `vector<string>`.

Для этого используйте метод `.string()` у `path`

```
vecImg.push_back(entry.path().string());
```